# ActiveAdmin Select2 not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, activeadmin, jquery-select2

I am using ActiveAdmin 1.0 (current master updated today). And have migrated from Chosen to Select2. I followed the directions at https://github.com/mfairburn/activeadmin-select2 but am noticing issues. If I navigate pages on the site, the css doesn't seem to be working. However if I am on a page and select the refresh button, the Select2 css shows up.

active_admin.js.coffee

```
#= require active_admin/base
#= require chosen-jquery
#= require_tree ./active_admin
#= require_tree .
#= require active_admin/select2
```

active_admin.css.scss

```
// SASS variable overrides must be declared before loading up Active Admin's styles.
//
// To view the variables that Active Admin provides, take a look at
// `app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/mixins/_variables.css.scss` in the
// Active Admin source.
//
// For example, to change the sidebar width:
// $sidebar-width: 242px;

// Active Admin's got SASS!
@import "active_admin/mixins";
@import "active_admin/base";
//@import "chosen";
//@import "active_admin/chosen";


//body.active_admin {
  @import "active_admin/select2/base";
//}
// Overriding any non-variable SASS must be done after the fact.
// For example, to change the default status-tag color:
//
//   .status_tag { background: #6090DB; }
```

Any ideas why I have to refresh every page for the css to load? I have cleared cache and precompiled assets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like this isn't a CSS issue, but an issue with your JS initialization and turbolinks. The problem lies on this line of code: https://github.com/mfairburn/activeadmin-select2/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/active_admin/select2/select2.js.coffee#L15 which isn't compatible with Turbolinks, as the `document.ready` event isn't called when making page transitions - you can read about Turbolink's event lifecycle here: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events

My suggestion would be to probably override the file I linked to above by creating a `assets/javascripts/active_admin/select2/select.coffee` in your own app tree containing this code:

```
'use strict';

initSelect2 = (inputs, extra = {}) ->
  inputs.each ->
    item = $(this)
    # reading from data allows <input data-select2='{"tags": ['some']}'> to be passed to select2
    options = $.extend(allowClear: true, extra, item.data('select2'))
    # because select2 reads from input.data to check if it is select2 already
    item.data('select2', null)
    item.select2(options)

$(document).on 'has_many_add:after', '.has_many_container', (e, fieldset) ->
  initSelect2(fieldset.find('.select2-input'))

$(document).on 'ready page:load', ->
  initSelect2($(".select2-input"), placeholder: "")
  return
```

(notice the  use of Turbolink's `page:load` event)